# Rooting problem Samsung Galaxy Core

Tags: rooting, system-error

I am using Samsung Galaxy Core GT I8262, I had a problem rooting my device. I rooted my android device before but now there is a problem when rooting my device with kingo android root and with any other apk application my phone is hanging and cannot be rooted anymore. Can I able to root my phone in future, what is the problem, why I cannot root my phone now ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. As you didn't give any specific details about your device including system version, my first guess would be to download framaroot and try to uninstall all root files that are probably left in your storage and are causing problems (or do factory reset). Then try rooting again.

Comment: My phone version is android jelly bean 4.1.2 i already did factory reset on my phone several times but I cannot root my device if I am rooting my device my phone is hanging for few seconds and automatically the program is closing and the fact framaroot application is not working on my phone like before